# Limit a section to a number of pages?

Tags: mactex, texshop

Is there a way I can limit a section to a specific number of pages ?

For example, I am currently in a section that must not exceed two pages, however I have not completed the previous section, so I cannot scale it to how it might look like in the PDF (type, compile, check, fix, compile, check etc)... I can also start a new Tex file and do it there, but that's not very efficient. Is there a way I can say this section cannot exceed two pages worth of words ?

Comment: Check number of page [every page](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/everypage).

Comment: @Eddy_Em Not sure of what you posted, i'm not an expert on this subject and hence the website confused me. Thanks though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a manual page break (`\clearpage`) before the section. You can then see how long it is. Once you're done editing and want the contiguous document, remove the `\clearpage`.